# Appium (Webdriver.io) cannot find element by xpath

Tags: android, automated-tests, appium, webdriver-io

I'm newbie in Appium so may do something wrong =(

technologies: TypeScript+Appium(wd.io)+Jasmine

But I've stuck with receiving the error:

Jasmine logs:

```
An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters ("//android.view.ViewGroup[@resource-id="com.app.dev.debug:id/toolbar"]//android.widget.TextView")
```

Appium logs:

```
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/03ca8b58-7487-4ef6-9b81-8287a23c4a48/element {"using":"xpath","value":"//android.view.ViewGroup[@resource-id=\"com.app.dev.debug:id/toolbar\"]//android.widget.TextView"}
[debug] [MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.findElement() with args: ["xpath","//android.view.ViewGroup[@resource-id=\"com.app.dev.debug:id/toolbar\"]//android.widget.TextView","03ca8b58-7487-4ef6-9b81-8287a23c4a48"]
[debug] [BaseDriver] Valid locator strategies for this request: xpath, id, class name, accessibility id, -android uiautomator
[debug] [BaseDriver] Valid locator strategies for this request: xpath, id, class name, accessibility id, -android uiautomator
[debug] [BaseDriver] Waiting up to 0 ms for condition
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] Sending command to android: {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"xpath","selector":"//android.view.ViewGroup[@resource-id=\"com.app.dev.debug:id/toolbar\"]//android.widget.TextView","context":"","multiple":false}}
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"xpath","selector":"//android.view.ViewGroup[@resource-id=\"com.app.dev.debug:id/toolbar\"]//android.widget.TextView","context":"","multiple":false}}
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command action: find
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Finding '//android.view.ViewGroup[@resource-id="com.app.dev.debug:id/toolbar"]//android.widget.TextView' using 'XPATH' with the contextId: '' multiple: false
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Failed to locate element. Clearing Accessibility cache and retrying.
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Finding '//android.view.ViewGroup[@resource-id="com.app.dev.debug:id/toolbar"]//android.widget.TextView' using 'XPATH' with the contextId: '' multiple: false
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Returning result: {"status":7,"value":"No element found"}
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] Received command result from bootstrap
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/03ca8b58-7487-4ef6-9b81-8287a23c4a48/element 500 232 ms - 164
```

while looking for element by xpath.

elements tree attached:
[image: elements tree]

code example below:

```
const deviceOptions: ServiceOptions = {
  desiredCapabilities: {
    platformName: 'android',
    app: './app-dev-debug.apk',
    appPackage: 'com.app.dev.debug',
    appActivity: 'com.app.dev.feature.start.StartActivity',
    avdReadyTimeout: 1000,
    udid: 'LGK350RGNBS4TS',
    deviceName: 'LG-K350',
    clearSystemFiles: true,
    newCommandTimeout: 120
  },
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 4723
  };
}

const driver = remote(deviceOptions);

const selector = '//android.view.ViewGroup[@resource-id="com.app.dev.debug:id/toolbar"]//android.widget.TextView';

it('test', () =>
  driver.init().element(selector).getText().then(text => expect(text).toBe('myText'))
);
```

What is wrong here? How to make it work?

Comment: Could you please provide us with the tree of your application?
The error is most likely linked to an incorrect selector

Comment: @PierreBaran, done =)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like in your selector you're not providing which 'By' should be used to find the element.

Please try the following way

```
it('test', () =>
  driver.init().element(by.xpath(selector)).getText().then(text => 
expect(text).toBe('myText'))
);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: unfortunately it's webdriver.io there no ***by*** =\

Answer (score 0):

found the solution:
added the ***.waitForExist(selector)***

```
it('test', () =>
  driver.init().waitForExist(selector).element(selector).getText().then(text => 
expect(text).toBe('myText'))
);
```